# Agrupar por DATE(), pero mostrar desagrupado

Tags: mysql, date, sql, time, subconsultas

Me expreso con más claridad. A ver, dispongo de una tabla "**ENTRADAS**" que almacena **ID**, **INICIO**, **FIN** más el código de la persona que realizo la entrada.

El caso es que deseo que aparezcan de agrupado por día todas las horas que ha realizado entrada y salida, se sobre entiende que puede salir y entrar varias veces el mismo día.

He conseguido llegar a esto:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/6

```
SELECT DATE( inicio ) AS DIAS, ID
FROM entradas
WHERE cod=1
GROUP BY DATE(INICIO)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

El caso es que sólo muestra un `ID` aunque haya varias de ese mismo día.

Aunque por más que pienso en una **subconsulta** no caigo concretamente en que hacer.

Todo esto lo intento sacar para mostrar este formato.

```
 COD    DATE() - TIME(INICIO) - TIME(FIN) - TIME(INICIO) - TIME(FIN) 
 32    04-09-19   12:22        12:34       15:30          16:56 
 32    02-09-19   14:00        15:30.....
```

Según entradas o salidas que disponga del mismo día

¿Es posible?
Adjunto la DB en SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/2/0

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pone un ejemplo de tus datos de entrada y de los datos de salida. usa el boton [edit] y agregalo en la pregunta

Comment: Pienso que lo necesitas es un order by en lugar de group by

Comment: @crrlos no llego a verlo aún así, ¿podrías decirme cómo lo has imaginado con el ORDER BY? Gracias.

Comment: @Crucheng podrías armarte un ejemplode tu base en [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Acabo de agregarlo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/2/0

Comment: ¿Quieres que te salgan todos los registros de entrada y salida separados por coma pero que aparezcan uno por fecha? ¿Algo como lo que te muestro a continuación? ¿Quieres que te salgan todos los registros pero que aparezca un campo con la fecha? ¿Algo como lo que te muestro a continuación? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/18

Comment: Oh! @OscarGarcia nunca había realizado una consulta de ese modo, lo que realmente quiero son las horas de cada día, pero lo que busco es que me aparezca por tablas, es decir, lo que has hecho en RANGO pero que cada una este en su INICIO y FIN.

COD - DIA - INICIO - FIN - INICIO - FIN - INICIO - FIN - INICIO - FIN

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/19 Sé que para sacar la hora le añado, el TIME pero mi problema esta en mostrar las tablas, por eso pensé en una subconsulta donde extraer el id de los días agrupados para mostrar su inicio y fin de cada agrupado.
No sé si me explico con claridad

Comment: No entiendo exactamente lo que quieres obtener. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo en tu pregunta de cómo deseas el resultado poniéndolo a mano? Así, al menos, nos haremos una mejor idea del resultado que deseas.

Comment: El resultado deseado sería este:
COD   -      DIA     -          INICIO   -  FIN    -     INICIO    -     FIN  
32           04-09-19           12:22        12:34       15:30           16:56

¿Podría usar un DISTINCT en el GROUP_CONCAT? @OscarGarcia 
Gracias por todo

Comment: Pon un ejemplo real con dos o tres registros de ejemplo. Sigo sin entender qué son esas horas y los textos en mayúsculas si son literales o el contenido de los campos y si van como texto en un mismo campo o cada uno en el suyo. Edita tu pregunta para agregar allí la información nueva. Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia te paso una consulta en Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/26 ,Por cada registro, quiero una columna.
También he editado la pregunta para que veas un ejemplo como me comentas.
Gracias y saludos

Comment: No es posible crear una columna por cada registro (y mucho menos si todas tienen el mismo nombre). Si esa información la vas a mostrar en una página web o aplicación debes hacerlo a ese nivel y no a nivel de SQL.

Comment: Es más, ¿necesitas detectar, además, cuando una salida se realiza en un día posterior para que cuente también en ese día? Estas cosas se pueden hacer en SQL, pero expandir registros como campos no.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Claro necesito que si FIN esta en un día posterior a INICIO, lo haga como ese día.
Gracias por todo, a nivel PHP lo tenía hecho, el problema me viene cuando intento hacer las sumas de horas a nivel lenguaje, así que pensé en pasar todos los valores y poder hacer la suma.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución más cercana a lo que buscaba puede ser esto:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/39

Luego el JSON de las horas de cada día lo recorres en busca de poder sumarlo y hacer un total de horas.

```
SELECT
  DATE(inicio) fecha,
    CONCAT('[',
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '{''inicio'':''',time(inicio),'''}'),
              ']'),
    CONCAT('[',
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '{''fin'':''',time(fin),'''}'),
              ']')
FROM ENTRADAS e
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY fecha ASC, inicio ASC
```

Con ayuda de @OscarGarcia

Comment: Así las horas dentro de un mismo día te podrían salir desordenadas. Si las quieres ordenadas puedes usar http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/33 Recuerda que no se hace corte de un día a otro.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49915/43 lo que no sé si corresponde por lugar al incio y fin da cada uno de ellos @OscarGarcia

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal algo como?

SELECT cod_pk, DATE( inicio ) AS DIAS,time( inicio ) AS inicio,time( fin ) AS fin
FROM entradas
WHERE cod_pk="32"
Order BY DATE(INICIO)
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: El problema de mostrarlo así es que me repite el día, es como realmente lo tenía en un principio, lo que estaba pensando es en agrupar por día pero sacar varias columnas de inicio y fin según tenga de entradas o salidas.
Gracias